# Why "I hadn't noticed" instead of "I didn't notice"/"I haven't notice"?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, perfect-constructions, past-vs-past-perfect

I see that *I hadn't noticed* is commonly used by native speakers, more than the pair *I didn't notice* and *I haven't noticed* ,in the following example

> People are being more careful nowadays, don't you think?

> I *hadn't noticed* that!

Is it a rule or is it just preference? And could I use that said pair as well (didn't/haven't noticed)? Or they differ?

Answer (score 4):

While the three say the same thing about the past, they say very different things about the present.

“I hadn’t noticed” means I didn’t notice that before, *but I do now*.

“I haven’t noticed” means I didn’t notice that before, *and I still don’t*.

“I didn’t notice” only refers to the past; it says nothing about the present.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't noticed generally means, "I hadn't noticed *until you mentioned it*"

The implication is that, before you mentioned it I hadn't noticed. Now that you have mentioned it I have noticed it (because you mentioned it)