# Which tense should I use here: "didn't live up to" or "hadn't lived up to"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

What is the difference between:

> Не said that the performance didn't live up to his expectations

and

> Не said that the performance hadn't lived up to his expectations?

Should we use Past Simple or Past Perfect?

Comment: I mean I didn't lived up in first variant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "I hadn't noticed" instead of "I didn't notice"/"I haven't notice"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260026/why-i-hadnt-noticed-instead-of-i-didnt-notice-i-havent-notice) One answer explains that the choice is a matter of what you would like to emphasize.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could say *hadn't*, but I think most people would use *didn't*, because we often don't use the past perfect when the temporal relationships are obvious.